# Display category posts before others category custom query

Tags: categories

I have a page display some posts categories.
So I want display before all post in my category 1 then, the others categories...

So I want have:
- display all posts in category 1 with descendent data
after all posts I want display all other categories

thanks

---

I find the solution:
So I have the first query args:

```
$prima = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'order'          => 'DESC',
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                //  'cat' => 41,
                'category__in' => array('41'),
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => 0,
                'nopaging' => true,
            );
```

The second query args

```
$seconda = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'order'          => 'DESC',
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                //  'cat' => 41,
                'category__in' => array('42,43'),

                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => 0,
                'nopaging' => true,
            );
```

So I find the post ids from the 2 queries and I add in the same array

```
// unique array
$array_primo_secondo = array();

// first loop
if ($query_prima->have_posts()) : while ($query_prima->have_posts()) : $query_prima->the_post();

                    $post_id_prima = get_the_ID();  
                    $array_primo_secondo[] =  $post_id_prima;
                endwhile;
            endif;

// second loop
if ($query_seconda->have_posts()) : while ($query_seconda->have_posts()) : $query_seconda->the_post();

                    $post_id_seconda = get_the_ID();
                    $array_primo_secondo[] =  $post_id_seconda;
                endwhile;
            endif;
```

Now I have the array with all the ID 
So I can do the last query

```
$args = array(
                // all the post in my array
                'post__in' => $array_primo_secondo,
                // I have the original pagination
                'paged' => $paged,
                'suppress_filters' => 0,
                // I have the order in the array
                'orderby' => 'post__in',
            );

            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. What have you tried and why is it not functioning?

Comment: use 2 queries.  first uses `category => 'cat-id'` and the second uses `category__not_in => 'cat-id'`

Comment: @rudtek but how can I add pagination with 2 queries?

Comment: @jdm2112 the problem is display before all my posts of category 1 and than display all other categories post, with pagination

Comment: are you paginating the first query or the 2nd?

Comment: I would paginate all queries..

Comment: That's a bit of a process.  You would have 2 pagination sets on the same page?  Would it keep the first set on the it's page if you clicked to page 3 of the 2nd?  So many questions you would need to address.

Comment: Try this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309057/two-queries-on-the-same-page-with-pagination

Comment: @jdm2112
I find the easiest solution, I edit the post and I write it. What about? Thanks

Comment: @rudtek I find the easiest solution, I edit the post and I write it. What about? Thanks